# How to parse a xml type HTTPResponse in Android

Tags: android, xml, httpresponse, xml-parsing

I have an android application where I use POST method to get a response. here is my code:

```
..........................................
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity =  httpResponse.getEntity();
```

this works fine and i get a response in xml format but i want to parse that xml file and get the node values. i tried this :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource());
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

but I don't know what should give to `new InputSource()` because I have to use a XML type HTTPResponse not a url.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok thanks everyone for the replies. i just found out a way to overcome my problem.
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0573.html

Answer (score 1):

try

```
InputStream is = resEntity .getContent()
Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any XML parser like SAX to parse ur XML Data

Answer (score 0):

if your response in xml string format follow

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is=new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString(ur response)))
Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Comment: hi, Aswan. thanks for the reply. but i am not clear with that is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString(ur response))) line can you please explain it. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
            getsyncFlag(String feedData) {

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            xr.setContentHandler(this);
            InputSource is=new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader((feedData)));
            xr.parse(is);
}
```