# error : The method parse() is undefined for the type HttpResponse

Tags: android

When I try to run some code, I am getting the following error:

```
The method parse() is undefined for the type HttpResponse
```

Here is my code:

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
strResp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
Document document = response.parse();
```

Comment: Are you trying to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206127/convert-http-response-to-xml-document-in-java)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method `parse()` for `HttpResponse`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to parse an HttpResponse ? 
It doesn't exist... Parse exist for a String
Maybe you wanted to do :

```
Document document = strResp.parse();
```

Which would work if strResp is a String. But maybe that's not what you want.

I do it like this (I found it on the web and it works perfectly for me) :

```
    public String getXmlFromUrlHttp(String url)  
{
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient            
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xml;
}
```

Then you parse the result of the function ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get a few solutions from: [How to parse a xml type HTTPResponse in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456925/how-to-parse-a-xml-type-httpresponse-in-android)

Probably something like:

```
...
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
Document doc = db.parse(is);
```